# How to add integers using input redirection in c++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am doing an assignment where I create a file called formula.txt which contains the following :

100 + 50 - 25 + 0 + 123 - 1

Now I have to use input redirection so the file reads the integers and gives me the sum for the above integers.

I have tried including strings as well as changing the type of the integers to char to take care of the + and - signs. I know cin takes in input and skips whitespace but my sum is not the desired sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int sum = 0; //sets sum to 0
  char input=0;// sets input to 0
  while(cin>>input) // reads inputs
  {
      sum+=input; // adds inputs 
  }

  cout << sum << endl; // adds input
}
```

I should get answer 247
Instead I got 835

Comment: What do you mean by "input redirection", specifically? Do you mean using the operating system's "pipe" feature or something else?

Comment: Looks like you 1) read characters rather than numbers and 2) always add when it looks like there is a subtraction involved. You need to write yourself a parser to separate the operands from operators and perform the appropriate operations on the operands.

Comment: Your code treats all input as the same. It should be obvious that a working program has to treat `+` and `-` and digits differently. You have to do that extra work, that's the point of the exercise. C++ isn't going to do it for you. This seems like a very difficult task to give to a beginner.

Comment: @Dai write numbers in separate file instead of in program. Those numbers act as my inputs instead of directly typing the numbers while program is running

Comment: @john I agree, how can I do that, I have not learned parsing yet

Comment: @user4581301 when I put int instead of char I get the answer 100, it does not add the numbers

Comment: It would take far too long to explain how to do parsing. There are whole books written on the subject. That's why I said this seems too difficult an exercise to give to a beginner.

Comment: @john is there another way?

Comment: IntisarRatul if you only read `int`, `while(cin>>input)` reads 100 and successfully converts it to an `int`. It then reads + and fails to convert it to an `int`. The while loop exits because of the failure. You have to switch back and forth between reading operands (`int`s) and operators (`std::string`s are probably easiest). Once you have the operands and operators you can apply the operators to the operands and get a meaningful answer.  @john isn't kidding. This is a problem that will likely take you a while to solve.

Comment: Lol I have been on this for a week, thanks though

Comment: @IntisarRatul - It seems to me you may be able to remove all whitespace between the tokens. Then, `int input; cin>>input` will parse positive and negative numbers without the need for a full lexer and tokenizer.

Answer (score 3):

First, you use `>>` for `char`s, which discards spaces.

The ascii values of the characters `100+50-25+0+123-1` are:

```
49, 48, 48, 43, 53, 48, 45, 50, 53, 43, 48, 43, 49, 50, 51, 45, 49
```

Their sum is `815`. That explains your output.
You should read in numbers and operator instead of individual characters.

To read in a file, you can use a `std::ifstream` like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs{"file name here"}; // NOTE: put your own file name here!!
    int sum;
    ifs >> sum;
    for (char c; ifs >> c;)
    {
        int num;
        ifs >> num;
        if (c == '+')
            sum += num;
        if (c == '-')
            sum -= num;
    }
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Or you can also the pipe syntax your system provides, which may be what you mean by "redirection."

Comment: is there a way to do this using getline function? or re-convert ascii to integers

Comment: @IntisarRatul I don't see how getline helps here. To re-convert ascii to integers use `char(55)`, for example, to get the character of ascii 55.

Comment: @IntisarRatul What did not work? Did you replace "file name here" with your own file?

Comment: @IntisarRatul Make sure to put your file name in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: @IntisarRatul Sorry Intisar, I made a silly mistake. Now it should work. Thank John for this.

Comment: @IntisarRatul If you meet further trouble, feel free to tell us. If this worked for you, you can upvote and/or accept the answer in case you are new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: it looks like I misunderstood what you were saying, I apologize, I ran again and it worked.  Is there anyway I could message you?

Answer (score 0):

Though the other one answers your question, Here is one of the approaches using `getline`. It is assumed that file has only one line.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

enum class Operation {
    ADD,
    SUBTRACT
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin {"<file to be opened>"};
    std::string str;

    std::getline(fin, str);
    std::istringstream sstr(str);

    std::string op;
    int ans = 0;
    Operation lastOperation = Operation::ADD;

    while (sstr >> op) {
        if (op == "+") {
            lastOperation = Operation::ADD;
        } else if (op == "-") {
            lastOperation = Operation::SUBTRACT;
        } else {
            int num = std::stoi(op);

            if (lastOperation == Operation::ADD) {
                ans += num;
            } else if (lastOperation == Operation::SUBTRACT) {
                ans -= num;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << ans << "\n";
}
```